# Can you use a conditional ternary operator by itself? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I tried using this construct:

```
function messageTest(data2, data1, value){
    (!value) ? if (data2 == 0x7F) return true :
                if (data1 == value && data2 == 0x7F) return false;
}
```

But I get a syntax error.  Can you use a ternary operator by itself like this?  Also I'm using WSH for this execution.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No - the "pieces" of a `? :` operator have to be *expressions*, and an `if` statement is definitely not an expression.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, and not all code paths return a value. What should happen, for instance, when `value` is false but `data2 != 0x7F`?

Comment: did you come from Ruby? :)

Comment: You could simplify to `return value && data1 != value || Boolean(value) == (data2 == 0x7F)`

Comment: @yefrem is this a stab at the readability of my code style? :)

Comment: no I was referring to your attempt to put `if` into unnatural place. But actually I didn't understand your idea clearly after the first look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have `if` and `return` statements inside the ternary, you have to do something like

```
return value ? !(data1 == value && data2 == 0x7F) : data2 == 0x7F;
```

note that I flipped it, as doing `!value` doesn't make sense in this case, and you could also do

```
return value ? (data1 != value || data2 != 0x7F) : data2 == 0x7F;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you use a conditional ternary operator by itself

Yes, any expression can be used by itself

> But I get a syntax error

This is because `return` and `if` can't be in the middle of an expression

Comment: It is not the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it, where (data2=== 0x7F) is evaluated as a bool instead of using the IF

```
function messageTest(data2, data1, value) {
  return (!value ? (data2 === 0x7F) : !((data1 === value) && (data2 === 0x7F)));
}
```